# Cannot use variables to pass parameter to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, exec

I would like to concatenate a string and pass to a procedure...  I can get it working on the first example hardcoded, but I need to pass it a dynamic filename - so need to get one of the below failures to work...

This hardcoding works fine:

```
exec master.dbo.sp_getfiledetails_CC 'c:\temp\test file.xml'
    , @filedate = @FileDateTime OUTPUT
```

This doesn't:

```
DECLARE @CCTMP as varchar(max)
set @cctmp = 'master.dbo.sp_getfiledetails_CC ''c:\temp\text file.xml''
    , @filedate = @FileDateTime OUTPUT'
exec @cctmp
```

This doesn't either:

```
DECLARE @CCTMP as varchar(max)
DECLARE @FileName as varchar(max)
set @filename = 'c:\temp\text file.xml'
set @cctmp = 'master.dbo.sp_getfiledetails_CC ' + @filename +'
    , @filedate = @FileDateTime OUTPUT'
exec @cctmp
```

And neither does this:

```
DECLARE @FileName as varchar(max)
set @filename = 'c:\temp\text file.xml'
exec master.dbo.sp_getfiledetails_CC ' + @filename +'
    , @filedate = @FileDateTime OUTPUT'
```

---

This is the procedure:

[dbo].[sp_getfiledetails_CC]

```
    (
        @filename NVARCHAR(255) = NULL --(full path)
        ,@filedate DATETIME OUTPUT
    )

AS
DECLARE @fileobj INT , @fsobj INT
DECLARE @exists INT, @error INT 
DECLARE @src VARCHAR(255), @desc VARCHAR(255)


--create FileSystem Object
EXEC @error = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @fsobj OUT
IF @error <> 0
BEGIN
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @fsobj, @src OUT, @desc OUT 
SELECT error=CONVERT(varbinary(4),@error), Source=@src, Description=@desc
RETURN 2
END

--check if specified file exists
EXEC @error = sp_OAMethod @fsobj, 'FileExists', @exists OUT, @filename

IF @exists = 0
BEGIN
--RAISERROR 22004 'The system cannot find the file specified.'
RETURN 2
END

--Create file object that points to specified file
EXEC @error = sp_OAMethod @fsobj, 'GetFile' , @fileobj OUTPUT, @filename
IF @error <> 0
BEGIN
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @fsobj
RETURN 2
END

--Declare variables holding properties of file
DECLARE @Attributes TINYINT, 
@DateCreated DATETIME, 
@DateLastAccessed DATETIME,
@DateLastModified DATETIME,
@Drive VARCHAR(1),
@Name NVARCHAR(255),
@ParentFolder NVARCHAR(255),
@Path NVARCHAR(255),
@ShortPath NVARCHAR(255),
@Size INT,
@Type NVARCHAR(255)

--Get properties of fileobject
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @fileobj, 'Attributes', @Attributes OUT
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @fileobj, 'DateCreated', @DateCreated OUT
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @fileobj, 'DateLastAccessed', @DateLastAccessed OUT 
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @fileobj, 'DateLastModified', @DateLastModified OUT 
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @fileobj, 'Drive', @Drive OUT
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @fileobj, 'Name', @Name OUT
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @fileobj, 'ParentFolder', @ParentFolder OUT
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @fileobj, 'Path', @Path OUT
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @fileobj, 'ShortPath', @ShortPath OUT
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @fileobj, 'Size', @Size OUT
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @fileobj, 'Type', @Type OUT

--destroy File Object
EXEC @error = sp_OADestroy @fileobj
IF @error <> 0
BEGIN
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @fileobj
RETURN
END

--destroy FileSystem Object
EXEC @error = sp_OADestroy @fsobj
IF @error <> 0
BEGIN
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @fsobj
RETURN 2
END


--return results
SELECT NULL AS [Alternate Name], 
@Size AS [Size], 
CONVERT(varchar, @DateCreated, 112) AS [Creation Date], 
REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, @DateCreated, 108), ':', '') AS [Creation Time], 
CONVERT(varchar, @DateLastModified, 112) AS [Last Written Date], 
REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, @DateLastModified, 108), ':', '') AS [Last Written Time], 
CONVERT(varchar, @DateLastAccessed, 112) AS [Last Accessed Date], 
REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, @DateLastAccessed, 108), ':', '') AS [Last Accessed Time], 
@Attributes AS [Attributes]

--SET @filedate = REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, @DateLastModified, 108), ':', '')
set @filedate = convert(datetime, CONVERT(float,@DateLastModified))
```

Comment: Have you tried sp_executesql?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: Usually it helps that instead of saying that something doesn't work you either include the error message or other description that what goes wrong

Comment: @James Z  the procedure just does not return anything

Comment: @Joe C could not get that to work either.

Comment: Ouch...sp_oacreate. I haven't wrangled that in a LONG time. You are likely going to need to add some auditing in here to see the values of your variables. You might also run a profiler trace when you run to see what values you are really passing. With everything you have posted it is about a 99.99999% chance that you are not calling that procedure with the same information as in your hard coded version.

Comment: Looking at this closer it highly likely you are getting an error and it is returning much earlier than the end of the code. You have several return statements in there. That would be a great place to add some auditing. Just some additional select statements so you can see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your question.

This doesn't work when passing an argument:

```
DECLARE @CCTMP as varchar(max)
set @cctmp = 'master.dbo.sp_who 1'
exec @cctmp
```

But it will work if you wrap varable in ():

```
DECLARE @CCTMP as varchar(max)
set @cctmp = 'master.dbo.sp_who 1'
exec (@cctmp)
```

So your example should look something like this:

```
declare @CCTMP as varchar(max)

set @cctmp = 'declare @FileDateTime datetime
exec master.dbo.sp_getfiledetails_CC ''c:\temp\text file.xml''
   , @filedate = @FileDateTime OUTPUT
select @FileDateTime'

-- create table to handle output of query
declare @output table (output varchar(max))
insert @output exec (@cctmp)

-- then you can pull your variable from @output
select * from @output
```

Comment: No luck with that.  The only one that works is my first one listed (hard-coded).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using dynamic sql. It is just adding a layer of confusion that you don't need.

What you are trying to do is the whole point of parameters. It would something as simple as this.

```
DECLARE @FileName as varchar(max)
set @filename = 'c:\temp\text file.xml'

declare @FileDateTime datetime

exec master.dbo.sp_getfiledetails_CC @filename, @FileDateTime OUTPUT
```

FWIW, not sure why you are creating procedures in master. Either way, the sp_ prefix is reserved by MS for system procedures and adding your own is risky. You can read more about why you should avoid that prefix here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Hi Sean, that is the same as option#4 above that I tried with no success.  Thanks for the info re: naming conventions - I will change that right away.

Comment: No that is not the same thing as you posted above. Your #4 has a strange string there. If that doesn't work then you need to share the procedure code and quite a bit more information.

Comment: I tried it - no luck.  I have added the procedure above now.  That should be good, I found it on here.